# Android annotation MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class not found

Tags: android, annotations

I try to use annotation in my app. I created interface as it's said in docs but MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class is not found. Could you tell me why ? EvenList is also not found :/

```
@Rest(converters = { MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MyRestClient {
    @Get("http://company.com/ajax/services/events")
    EventList getEvents();
}
```

Annotation works fine. My build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.2'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.example.package.name'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android Annotation [REST API](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API) is a wrapper around the [Spring Android](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e231) RestTemplate Module.
Therefore you need to add android spring [dependencies](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) to your gradle files.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to include line below to your implementation class

`import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;`